# Почему redux вызывает одну и ту же thunk-функцию 2 раза?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, redux-thunk

Всем привет. Я пытаюсь переделать свою пагинацию пользователей с полной их замены на добавление новых к предыдущим. И тут я заметил проблему. Почему-то при нажатии на кнопку подгрузки новых пользователей redux вызывает мою thunk-функцию 2 раза. Причем, в первый раз, когда только заходишь на страницу пользователей и делается первый запрос все работает нормально. Я проверил, с useEffect-ами все нормально + я убрал React.StrickMode. В итоге первые 10(лимит запроса) пользователей у меня загружаются нормально, а уже далее при подгрузке новых пользователей они дублируются.

```
export const getUsers = (currentPage, pageSize) => async (dispatch) => {
dispatch(toggleIsFetching(true));
dispatch(updateCurrentPage(currentPage));

const data = await usersAPI.getUsers(currentPage, pageSize);
await dispatch(setUsers(data.items));
await dispatch(setTotalUsersCount(data.totalCount));
dispatch(toggleIsFetching(false));}

const usersReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_FOLLOW:
        return {
            ...state,
            users: state.users
                .map(user => user.id === action.userId ? {...user, followed: !user.followed} : user),
        }

    case  SET_USERS:
        return {
            ...state,
            users: [...state.users, ...action.users],
        }

    case  SET_TOTAL_USERS_COUNT:
        return {
            ...state,
            totalUsersCount: action.totalUsersCount,
        }

    case  UPDATE_CURRENT_PAGE:
        return {
            ...state,
            currentPage: action.currentPage,
        }

    case TOGGLE_IS_FETCHING:
        return {
            ...state,
            isFetching: action.isFetching,
        }

    case TOGGLE_IS_FOLLOWING_USER:
        return {
            ...state,
            followingUsersInProcess: action.isFetching ?
                [...state.followingUsersInProcess, action.userId] :
                state.followingUsersInProcess.filter(id => id !== action.userId),
        }

    default:
        return state;
}}
```

Comment: почему мне кажется что useEffect с диспатчом санки вызывается два раза? добавь сюда тот самый useEffect
и еше момент dispatch(updateCurrentPage(currentPage)); эта штука обновляет страницу? может она запускает useEffect еше раз

Comment: Привет) Ну, повторюсь, я проверял, useEffect вызывается только один раз. Я сам изначально на него и грешил, но, вроде, он чист)
`useEffect(() => {
        props.getUsers(props.currentPage, props.pageSize);
    }, [props.currentPage, props.pageSize, props.getUsers])`
А вот насчет updateCurrentPage нужно будет подумать.

Comment: Я убрал updateCurrentPage и все заработало) Спасибо за наводку

Comment: рад был помочь)